# How to get the url parameters after an occurance

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to get the URL parameters from the browser.

the browser has the URL like this

```
http://localhost/red/prepareslide.php?p=trng&s=1
```

but i want to get the params that is, i want to get the all params after(question mark) "?"

output should be like this `p=trng&s=1`
how can i do this?

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</head>
<script>
function call(){
URL = window.location.toString();

var query = URL.match(/\?/);
alert(query);
var queryList = query.split("?");
for (var i=0; i<queryList.length; i++) 
{
var element = queryList[i].split("=");
var ex=document.write(element[0] + " = " + unescape(element[1]) + "\r\n");
alert(ex);
}
}
</script>



</head>
<body>

<a href="#" onclick="call();">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.location.search` (includes `?`) and decodeURIComponent is better than unescape

Comment: window.location.search.substring(1)

Comment: @Chandan raikar can you please update your question saying you want to get request parameter names and their values if this is making any sense to you?

Answer (score 2):

*edit : some1 notified that my snippet contains a flaw. He is right. If there is no question mark in the URL, the result will be the full url.*

Since you are aiming to get the characters after the question mark, this should do the job,

```
// obtain browser url
var currUrl = document.URL;
// split string to obtain substring
var index; var str;
if((index = currUrl.indexOf("?")) > 0) str = currUrl.substring(index + 1);
```

But this can be quicker indeed. Like commented below,

```
// obtain browser url
var currUrl = document.URL;
// replace the string that only after ? returns as results
var str = currUrl.replace(/^[^?]*\?/, '');
// check result
if(str != '') {
    // do your task here with the result 
}
```

If you want to give credit if this is an useful reply, please give it to ElLocoCocoLoco (for his remark) and/or Ruslan Bes for replace trick. (is correct too though).

Comment: Or `currURL.replace(/^\?/, '')`, to be even shorter.

Comment: @Utkanos Not exactly. `var str = currUrl.replace(/^[^?]*\?/, '')` is more likely. And BTW indexOf solution is almost surely faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can;

```
document.location.search.replace(/\??([^&=]+)=([^&=]*)/g, function(p, k, v) {
    document.write(k + " = " + decodeURIComponent(v) + "</ br>");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the params part, you can try as follows :

```
var urlParams = window.location.href.split('?')[1] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the right and complete way to do it**:

```
    var url = window.location.href;

    var endChar = url.indexOf('#');
    if(endChar==-1)
    {
        endChar = url.length;
    }
    var queryChar = url.indexOf('?');

    var queryPart="";
    if(queryChar!=-1)
    {
        queryPart = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1,endChar);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your RE **/\?/** will only return **?**, you should use 
**/\?\S+/**, that will result **?p=trng&s=1**, then use the split() accordingly, #also handle the unwanted symbal ? in the result.